# How to use a single search box for multiple domains or websites in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, content-management-system, search-engine

Actually I have two different domains in which second one is a sub domain for first one so I want to use a single search box for the both domains. The both websites are designed using wordpress technology.

Meaning: 
               The first site is my main site (Wordpress) and the second site (Wordpress) is like a search engine so if user wants to search anything he will search his need from my main site so I wanted to connect that first site search box to my second site (search engine).

Answer (score 0):

Am I right : your two websites have two distinct databases ? Therefore there is no simple way to search in the two sites at once.

You could do it like this :

1. Create separate tables, containing a copy of the data of the two sites.
2. Have a cron job keeping these tables up to date.
3. Connect your search box to these tables.
4. Modify the display of the result in order to link to the correct site of both.

Comment: Hi sir this is saketh. Thanks for ur help. I was totally confused with the above process so can u please elaborate this. thanks again for helping.

Comment: After reading the question again, maybe this was not the right answer. I read that you want your search box give results from two websites simultaneously. You wrote, that you want to search on one domain and have the results on another. This is much easier than what I was thinking about. I think there must be a way to do this in wordpress itself without messing around with additional tables. Unfortunately, I'm not a wordpress specialist, so I cannot guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Google Custom Search (free up to 11 domains)